# What happened to the windows() function

Tags: r

Sorry if the answer is obvious. I'm using the R book (2nd ed) and they describe how to use the windows() function to change the window size. E.g., you could specify:

```
windows(7,4)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

And now you could nicely ask for two plots and they wouldn't be "squished" horizontally.

However, when I went to invoke windows(), I can see the function is no longer a part of the grDevices package.

Any idea how to adjust the window size??

Comment: What version of R are you using? On what operating system? Can you do `dev.new(width=7,height=4)`?

Comment: How does windows() show you that it's no longer part of grDevices? Tell us

Comment: Looks like it is there in the development version of R: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/00a16298a767da90a20561449aee3b4d60ce4445/src/library/grDevices/R/windows/windows.R#L60

Comment: Version 3.02. Looks like it actually works nicely in the base R console, but it not implemented by RStudio. Thanks